# How to iterate through JSON to print in a formatted way

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

This is the JSON i have

```
"""
{   "A":1,
    "B":[
      {
        "C":
      {
        "D": "0"
      },
      "E":
      {
        "F": "1",
        "G": [
          {
            "H": {
              "I": 12,
              "J": 21
            }
          }
        ]
      }
      }
    ]
}
    

    
    
"""
```

I want to print the JSON in the following way more likely in a tree fashion

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------EXPECTED OUTPUT!-----------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

{
            'title': 'ROOT',
            'key': '0',
            'children': [

                {
                    'title': 'A',
                    'key': 'A',
                    'children':[]
                },
                {
                    'title': 'B',
                    'key': 'B',
                    'children':[
                        {
                            'title': 'C',
                            'key': 'C',
                            'children':[
                                {
                                    'title': 'D',
                                    'key': 'D',
                                    'children':[]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            'title': 'E',
                            'key': 'E',
                            'children':[
                                {
                                    'title': 'F',
                                    'key': 'F',
                                    'children':[]
                                },{
                                    'title': 'G',
                                    'key': 'G',
                                    'children':[
                                        {
                                            'title': 'H',
                                            'key': 'H',
                                            'children':[
                                                {
                                                    'title': 'I',
                                                    'key': 'I',
                                                    'children':[]
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    'title': 'J',
                                                    'key': 'J',
                                                    'children':[]
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }

                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
                ]                   
}
```

here is the reference to the above printing pattern [link](https://github.com/kapot65/dash-treeview-antd#values) !

Here is the code i tried

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

json_data = json.loads("""
{   "A":1,
    "B":[
      {
        "C":
      {
        "D": "0"
      },
      "E":
      {
        "F": "1",
        "G": [
          {
            "H": {
              "I": 12,
              "J": 21
            }
          }
        ]
      }
      }
    ]
}
    
""")

__version__ = '1.0.0'
_branch_extend = '│  '
_branch_mid = '├─ '
_branch_last = '└─ '
_spacing = '   '

last_items = []

main_json_obj = {
    'title': """ ROOT """, 'key': 'ROOT',
    'children': []
}


def _getHierarchy(jsonData, name='', file=None, _prefix='', _last=True):
    """ Recursively parse json data to print data types """
    # Handle object datatype
    if isinstance(jsonData, dict):
        name = name
        print(_prefix, _branch_last if _last else _branch_mid, \
              name, sep="", file=file)
        if _last:
            last_items.append([{'title': name, 'key': name, 'children': []}])
        main_json_obj['children'] += [{'title': name, 'key': name, 'children': []}]
        _prefix += _spacing if _last else _branch_extend
        length = len(jsonData)
        for i, key in enumerate(jsonData.keys()):
            _last = i == (length - 1)
            _getHierarchy(jsonData[key], '"' + key + '"', file, _prefix, _last)
    # Handle array datatype
    elif isinstance(jsonData, list):
        # name += ' (array)'
        print(_prefix, _branch_last if _last else _branch_mid, \
              name, sep="", file=file)
        if _last:
            last_items.append([{'title': name, 'key': name, 'children': []}])

        main_json_obj['children'] += [{'title': name, 'key': name, 'children': []}]
        _prefix += _spacing if _last else _branch_extend
        _getHierarchy(jsonData[0], '', file, _prefix, _last=True)
    else:
        # Handle string datatype
        if isinstance(jsonData, str):
            name = name
            if _last:
                last_items.append([{'title': name, 'key': name, 'children': []}])

            main_json_obj['children'] += [{'title': name, 'key': name, 'children': []}]
        # Handle number datatype
        else:
            name = name
            if _last:
                last_items.append([{'title': name, 'key': name, 'children': []}])

            main_json_obj['children'] += [{'title': name, 'key': name, 'children': []}]
        print(_prefix, _branch_last if _last else _branch_mid, \
              name, sep="", file=file)


def setSymbols(branch_extend='│  ', branch_mid='├─ ', branch_last='└─ '):
    """ Override symbols for the tree structure """
    global _branch_extend
    global _branch_mid
    global _branch_last
    _branch_extend = branch_extend
    _branch_mid = branch_mid
    _branch_last = branch_last

print("-----------------------------------------------------------")
print("-------------------Hierarchy is shown below--------------- ")
print("-----------------------------------------------------------")
print(" ")
_getHierarchy(json_data)
print(" ")
print("-----------------------------------------------------------")
print("-------------------Hierarchy ENDS HERE !--------------- ")
print("-----------------------------------------------------------")

print("      ")
print("      ")
print("--------------------OUTPUT AT THE MOMENT !!!!!!--------------    ")
print("      ")
print("      ")
pprint(main_json_obj)
print("      ")
print("      ")
```

this is its output at the moment!

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
-------------------Hierarchy is shown below--------------- 
-----------------------------------------------------------
 
└─ 
   ├─ "A"
   └─ "B"
      └─ 
         ├─ "C"
         │  └─ "D"
         └─ "E"
            ├─ "F"
            └─ "G"
               └─ 
                  └─ "H"
                     ├─ "I"
                     └─ "J"
 
-----------------------------------------------------------
-------------------Hierarchy ENDS HERE !--------------- 
-----------------------------------------------------------
      
      
--------------------OUTPUT AT THE MOMENT !!!!!!--------------    
      
      
{'children': [{'children': [], 'key': '', 'title': ''},
              {'children': [], 'key': '"A"', 'title': '"A"'},
              {'children': [], 'key': '"B"', 'title': '"B"'},
              {'children': [], 'key': '', 'title': ''},
              {'children': [], 'key': '"C"', 'title': '"C"'},
              {'children': [], 'key': '"D"', 'title': '"D"'},
              {'children': [], 'key': '"E"', 'title': '"E"'},
              {'children': [], 'key': '"F"', 'title': '"F"'},
              {'children': [], 'key': '"G"', 'title': '"G"'},
              {'children': [], 'key': '', 'title': ''},
              {'children': [], 'key': '"H"', 'title': '"H"'},
              {'children': [], 'key': '"I"', 'title': '"I"'},
              {'children': [], 'key': '"J"', 'title': '"J"'}],
 'key': 'ROOT',
 'title': ' ROOT '}
```

If you observer closely, The difference between the output i want and the output i got is that the child item are being printed separately as a dictionary. But, i want to include them inside the children list of the parent.

For example the key "A" doesn't have any children. So, it should be printed as a separate dictionary and its working this way as of now. But if you look at the key "B" it has keys "C" and "E" as its children. so "E and C" should be included inside B's Children. moreover the keys "E and C" have children themselves, for "C" the child "D" and for "E" the children are "F" and "G"  so "F and G" should be included in the children list of "E" . "D"   should be inside children list of "C".

any help would be really appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the JSON tree you've mentioned exactly what you wanted? What do you mean by regions? Also I don't see much difference between the expected JSON nested structure versus the current output. Can you update the question and add these details to it?

Comment: @ThePyGuy Thanks for the reply . Yes I want the out as i mentioned in the EXPECTED OUTPUT !. I have modified the question to add details to it. hope it helps 

Comment: Are you sure `key` shall have the same value as `title`? What is the point of those int values associated to each node?

Comment: yes i want to have the key same as the title

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple recursion:

```
def tree(json_data):
    def _tree(obj):
        if isinstance(obj, dict):
            return [{'title': k, 'key': k, 'children': _tree(v)}
                    for k, v in obj.items()]
        elif isinstance(obj, list):
            return [elem
                    for lst in map(_tree, obj)
                    for elem in lst]
        else:
            return []
    return {'title': 'ROOT', 'key': '0', 'children': _tree(json_data)}
```

Test:

```
>>> json_data = json.loads("""{
...     "A": 1,
...     "B": [
...         {
...             "C": {
...                 "D": "0"
...             },
...             "E": {
...                 "F": "1",
...                 "G": [
...                     {
...                         "H": {
...                             "I": 12,
...                             "J": 21
...                         }
...                     }
...                 ]
...             }
...         }
...     ]
... }""")
>>> pp(tree(json_data), width=1)
{'title': 'ROOT',
 'key': '0',
 'children': [{'title': 'A',
               'key': 'A',
               'children': []},
              {'title': 'B',
               'key': 'B',
               'children': [{'title': 'C',
                             'key': 'C',
                             'children': [{'title': 'D',
                                           'key': 'D',
                                           'children': []}]},
                            {'title': 'E',
                             'key': 'E',
                             'children': [{'title': 'F',
                                           'key': 'F',
                                           'children': []},
                                          {'title': 'G',
                                           'key': 'G',
                                           'children': [{'title': 'H',
                                                         'key': 'H',
                                                         'children': [{'title': 'I',
                                                                       'key': 'I',
                                                                       'children': []},
                                                                      {'title': 'J',
                                                                       'key': 'J',
                                                                       'children': []}]}]}]}]}]}
```

Comment: firstly thanks for the efforts . is it possible to add the values in the title  as well for example  "A" has value of 1 so the title for "A" should be "A : 1" and for "D" it should be "D : 0"

Comment: @180040170 Yes, simply change the  `'title': k` of the first branch to `'title': f'{k}: {v}'`.

Comment: Thanks a lot this did the trick `return [{'title': f'{k}: {v if not isinstance(v,(list,dict)) else " " }', 'key': k, 'children': _tree(v)} `

Comment: @DeLorean I think writing a simple function here will be more readable.